# How to cut a list or a display in multiple parts

Tags: python, python-3.x

i'm making a function in python supposed to convert Decimal(10) to Binary(2);

As it is supposed to be displayed on small screens (calculators), i would like to split the output bytes per bytes (8 by 8). For now, i use a list that i convert to string in order to display the result horizontally.

I've tried displaying vertically, pausing every 8 characters. (It worked but i would like to have an horizontal display);

Also tried to display the list and clear it every 8 characters but did not managed to.

```
def dectobin(dec):
  maxbin = 7
  maxdec = 2**maxbin
  dec2 = dec
  bin = []

#Define default maximum values 
#for the Binary and Decimal numbers
#starting from one Byte

  dec = abs(dec)

#Negative value to positive value

  while dec > maxdec:
    maxbin = maxbin+8
    maxdec = 2**maxbin

#Define the actual maximum values
#for the Binary and Decimal numbers
#incremented in Bytes

  while maxbin != -1:

#Set the loop to stop at final bit

    b = dec-2**maxbin

#Saving dec into another var
#in order to do the tests

    if b < 0:
      bin.append("0")

#If dec < maxbin value, it's a 0

    else:
      bin.append("1")

#If dec > maxbin value, it's a 1

      dec=b

    maxbin = maxbin-1

#Decrease the bit

  bin = " ".join(bin)
  print(dec2, "=", bin)
```

As an example, if I input "259" i would like to have

```
259 = 00000001
00000011
```

Instead of

```
259 = 0000000100000011
```

Comment: Could you provide a sample case with an input and the desired output?

Comment: @VasilisG. I added an example

Comment: Wrt the answers I expect that you are using python3, please add it to your tags, because the print statements differed between python2 and python3 while reproducing your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can slice `bin` to achieve your desired result. Modify your code right before you print to:

```
bin = "".join(bin)
bin = "\n".join([bin[i:i+8] for i in range(0, len(bin), 8)])
print(dec2, "=", bin)
```

This will give you:

```
259 = 00000001
00000011
```

What is the logic behind this?

In the first line you use `join` to create a string with all binary digits, separated by an empty space character. That means that for every 8 bits there are 8 empty 7 empty characters in between, forming a total of 15 characters that need to be taken into account when slicing bin. Thus, I used 16 to slice every 15 characters and get the result you want.

I would advice you to change `bin = " ".join(bin)` to `bin = "".join(bin)` so that the separator would be an empty string and split the list every 8 characters, which is normal and more readable for you. Feel free to ask anything else.

Comment: It works now! Thanks! Could you explain how what you added works, please ?

Comment: @Mazeo sure, let me edit it one more time to be fully correct and I will inform you.

Comment: In the first line you use `join` to create a string with all binary digits, separated by an empty space character. That means that for every 8 bits there are 8 empty 7 empty characters in between, forming a total of 15 characters that need to be taken into account when slicing `bin`. Thus, I used `16` to slice every 15 characters and get the result you want. I would advice you to change `bin = " ".join(bin)` to `bin = "".join(bin)` so that the separator would be an empty string and split the list every 8 characters, which is normal and more readable for you. Feel free to ask anything else.

Comment: @usr2564301 thanks for noticing. I will add it in my answer.

Comment: bin = "\n".join([bin[i:i+8] for i in range(0, len(bin), 8)]) instead of line 2, I would prefer.